# How to copy a Shape to another worksheet (not as a picture)?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a bit of a trouble (once again...) with Excel VBA.

I just want to copy Shapes (which are in fact "templates" shapes, with pre-defined layout) from a Worksheet to another Worksheets.

When I record a macro, this is the generated VBA code :

```
    Sheets("Layout").Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("CHART_TEMPLATE").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    Sheets("Example").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Of course, I want to get rid of all `".Select"` methods, for performance issue. For this reason, I can't `Select` a range, neither use `ActiveSheet.Paste`

Unfortunately, the `Paste` method only exists for `Worksheet` objects (like `ActiveSheet.Paste`), so I had to use the `PasteSpecial` method of `Range` objects.

So here's my code :

```
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Layout").ChartObjects("CHART_TEMPLATE").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Example").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
```

But, the `PasteSpecial` method copies `Shapes` as pictures...
Of course I don't want pictures, because I have to populate those `Charts`with data.

Does someone have a clue here ?

Thanx,

Comment: The Paste method can take a destination as an argument. Have you tried something like `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Example").Paste Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Example").Range("A1")` ?

Comment: I have posted the answer so you can close the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Paste method can take a destination as an argument. Have you tried something like this?

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Example").Paste Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Example").Range("A1")
```