# Excel VBA Copy and reposition logos across multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently looking to put together a simple excel workbook filled with several dozen template forms we use (one per worksheet). As part of this I am looking to have a "master" sheet at the front which can with the press of a macro copy information into all the other worksheets.

Doing this for the cells has been easy, but I have had limited success in copying across any logos. My intention is to put my company's logo at the top right of the form and any client logos at the top left, hit a button and the 2-3 logos will appear in the same place across all the other worksheets.

I've managed to reposition the logos individually by name with the following code:

```
For Each Shape In Worksheet.Shapes
       If Shape.Name = "OurLogo" Then
        Shape.Left = (Wb1.Sheets("Inputs").Shapes("Our Logo").Left - 1)
        Shape.Top = (Wb1.Sheets("Inputs").Shapes("Our Logo").Top - 1)
        End If
        Next Shape
```

Where Our Logo is the original logo and OurLogo is the copied and named logo.

However this means I need the logos already copied into the correct cell in each workbook with the correct name. I've managed to copy the logo across all the worksheets, but not been able to rename them as I've been going, they are just assigned "Picture#" as a name. I tried including a rename in a similar "For Each" macro to copy it across all the sheets, but this only renamed one logo pasted into the active worksheet and didn't rename any in the remaining worksheets.

Any advice on how to copy and rename these pictures to multiple worksheets while also renaming them would be greatly appreciated. Alternatively I would accept copying first and a method of renaming after with a second macro.

Thanks in advance for your help.

I previously tried the How to copy a Shape to another worksheet (not as a picture)?, method but setting the destination cell simply dumped the logo in the top left corner, looking very untidy when I wanted it centred - hence the repositioning macro based on the position of the original logo. The method under that link also renamed the logo to "Picture#", creating the renaming requirement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy a Shape to another worksheet (not as a picture)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465124/how-to-copy-a-shape-to-another-worksheet-not-as-a-picture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done this with 1 shape

```
Sub CopyAndRenameShape()

    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim wks As Worksheet

    Set sh = Sheet1.Shapes("shtTest")

    For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wks.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
            sh.Name = wks.Name & "_" & sh.Name
            sh.Copy
            wks.Paste
        End If
    Next wks
    sh.Name = "shtTest"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that. For some reason using this method of copying and pasting doesn't seem to rename the picture and I can just reposition it by name without having to perform any renaming. I would note that the macro you suggested ended up with every worksheet being in the name of the shape, e.g. "Sheet1_Sheet2_Sheet3...Picture1" so perhaps isn't suited to larger spreadsheets. Removing the renaming portion made it suit my purposes perfectly though, thanks!

Comment: yaah you got that right, it should be like this **sh.Name = wks.Name & "_" & "shtTest"**

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd result when Googling for "Excel VBA shape copy" point to a nifty question here at SE.

[How to copy a Shape to another worksheet (not as a picture)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465124/how-to-copy-a-shape-to-another-worksheet-not-as-a-picture)

Pretty sure that will solve your problem.

Comment: I had seen, and used, that article before, but specifying the cell destination would just plonk the picture/shape in the top left corner of the cell, looking very untidy. Additionally it would also rename any picture I copied as "Picture#", limiting my options for repositioning them afterwards. Arya's solution below solved my issue with a little adjusting. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Glad you found a solution - make sure you give him/her credit for it!  Once 'plonked' (nice word!) I'd imagine you'll still have to adjust the top-left position to get it where you want it.

Comment: Yes, once it has been 'plonked' into the sheet I reposition it using the code I referenced above. Simple enough if the name of the picture is kept the same as I can just reposition all pictures with the correct name across all workbooks - using the original logo/template as the basis. For some reason the name was getting changed to Picture# when I was using the other method, in your link, to copy and paste the logo. Credit has been given.